# What does the container size means in Cloudbees?

Tags: cloud, cloudbees

I am new to cloud, and I am using Cloudbees, and I want to know what does the container size means, and when to increase/decrease it ?

My application is J2EE application deployed on Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers are like a self contained boxes on the cloud in which you put and run your application.

Cloudbees provide free container but with limited functionality like memory, RAM and number of applications that can be created although you can upgrade according to your requirement on pay as you go basis which means you can grow when you feel you need a little more juice for your application.

Good Luck!